# AWS CodeBuild with S3 source: Error calling startBuild: Source version should be empty for S3 folder source location

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have this CodeBuild project as part of a wider CloudFormation template

```
  BuildDockerImageProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    DependsOn: CodeBuildRole
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-BuildDockerImageProject
      Artifacts:
        Type: no_artifacts
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        PrivilegedMode: true
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Source:
        BuildSpec: buildDocker.yml
        Type: S3
        Location: bucket-name/
```

When I deploy it I see this error on the CodeBuild:

`Error calling startBuild: Source version should be empty for S3 folder source location`

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because when you use S3 as the source for a CodeBuild project and specify the bucket root only as the `Location`.

A zip file must be specified in `Location`